# NoReverseMatch Django with negative content_type_id

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I know for some this question may seem similar to other NoReverseMatch Errors, but it isn't

I am using Djangae Framework over Django, to support Google Appengine. I have made a Custom GaeDatastoreUser, extending GaeAbstractBaseUser, and registered the model with `admin.site.register()`.

**models.py**

```
class ChatUser(GaeAbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # ID Constants

    class Meta:
        app_label = "chat_auth"
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
        verbose_name = _('chat user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('chat users')

    app_id = models.CharField(_('app_id'), max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    gcm_key = models.CharField(_('key'), max_length=128, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(_('mobile'), max_length=10, default="", null=True)
```

Viewing the list of all custom users at `/admin/chat_auth/chatuser/` on Django's Admin Site is working, but whenever I select a particular user to modify/delete it, I get a

```
NoReverseMatch at /admin/chat_auth/chatuser/5818821692620800/change/
Reverse for 'view_on_site' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'object_id': 5818821692620800L, 'content_type_id': -4929820764642951528L}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'admin/r/(?P<content_type_id>\\d+)/(?P<object_id>.+)/$']
```

As you can see I am getting a **negative ContentType ID** for any custom admin user (I don't know why). I have changed AUTH_USER_MODEL, and done everything [djangae's documentation](http://djangae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gauth/) said.

If I try to use djangae's default GaeDatastoreUser, these links work fine, only when I make a custom user, these links don't work.

Do I need to change something in urls.py, but I don't think so, else they would have provided some documentation on it.

I am sure it's because of negative content_type_id, but what is creating this, is something I am getting

**Edit**

*app.yaml*

```
- url: /admin.*
  script: {project}.wsgi.application
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

Comment: Yes, this is a URL matching issue.  In `app.yaml`, how are you handling calls to `/admin/...`?

Comment: My `app.yaml` file is the same as Google has mentioned in their docs, to use login:admin for restricting unknown users. Still, with these same specs, default Djangae's Datastore User works fine, issue arises only when i customize the admin user